# Convert Iterable to RDD in spark graphx

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have the product of a groupBy on the vertices of a graph

```
    val filteredNodesGroups = somegraph.vertices.groupBy{ 
        case(_, attr) => 
        {
            attr
        }
    }
```

and I would like to create a new graph for each group of vertices, for example

```
    for ((i,nodegroup) <- filteredNodesGroups){

        ...<transformation to produce a nodegroupRDD from nodegroup>...

        var gr = Graph(nodegroupRDD, somegraph.edges)
    }
```

The problem is that `nodegroup` is of type `Iterable[(VertexId, String)]`, meaning that each nodegroup is no longer an RDD.

How can I get past this, that is, how can I recreate RDD structures for each `nodegroup`? In other words, hat can I replace the `...<>...` code with, in order to make it work?

I tried to use the parallelize option, but from what I read it should not be possible, neither the correct way to do this.

I would appreciate any help.
Cheers

Comment: Spark doesn't accept RDD of RDDs, but you cannot use Graph for Lists, so the only option might be to filter your RDD and use Graph individually. It is really inefficient though... I guess alternatively, you could collect to a List of RDDs and then use sc.parallelize, but that again, is inefficient...

Comment: The thing is, you cannot pass the sc inside this iteration, so sc.parallelize cannot be used in this case.

Comment: I think you can, if you have somegraph.vertices as a List instead of a RDD, you could still use scala groupBy which will generate a scala.collection.immutable.Map. You can then convert the Iterable into a RDD by writing a function that contains sc.parallelize. The result is a Map of RDDs. Now, I don't think it makes much sense to parallelize the map to get RDD of RDDs (Although I think compiler might let you do it), but if you are to reduce the result, then it works fine).

Comment: This is my example: def para (a: List[(String, Int)])={
  sc.parallelize(a).reduce((x,y)=>(x._1+","+y._1,x._2+y._2))
}
val t1 = List(("a",1),("a",2)).groupBy(_._1).map(x=>(x._1,para(x._2.toList)))

Answer (score 2):

If number of unique attributes is relatively small you can collect and create RDDs locally:

```
 val attrs = somegraph.vertices.map{case (_, attr) => attr}.distinct.collect

 val grahps = attrs.map(attr => {
     val vertices = somegraph.vertices.filter{case (_, someAttr) =>
          someAttr == attr
     }
     val edges = somegraph.edges.filter(...) 
     Graph(vertices, edges)
 })
```

Note that you should probably filter `edges` as well, otherwise you'll get a bunch of vertices with `null` attribute.

Another approach is to use `GraphOps.filter`. It is probably more efficient but you still need to provide values to filter.

Comment: Unfortunately there seem to be quite a few distinct attributes occurring from the groupBy, which means that indeed this might be rather costly. However, if I don't find anything else, I will have to use it.

Comment: Why do you need something like this in the first place? If number of the unique attributes is large creating respective number of RDDs will be the limiting factor anyway.

Comment: I break the graph into smaller graphs and calculate the pagerank in each subgraph.

Comment: If number of groups is large I doubt there is a good solution. If you had a moderate number of unique values I would probably recommend dropping an idea of multiple RDDs and implementing something like topic sensitive page rank from scratch using `aggregateMessages`.